# comment the <xref> tags and keep the text as plain, if xref/@href value is not matched with section/@id

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to comment the `xref` tags and keep the text as plain, if `xref/@href` attribute value is not matched with `section/@id` attibute value.

I have created the xsl code for comment the `xref` tags but unable to get the expected result.

Please see the expected result and suggest

Thanks in advance!

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book id="book_id">
    <title>Generally Accepted Accounting Principles</title>
    <chapter id="chapter_id" role="ls_level_2">
        <chapterinfo>
            <titleabbrev>Chapter_abb</titleabbrev>
            <title>Chapter_title</title>
        </chapterinfo>
        <section id="aag-dep1_01">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>containing auditing <xref href="fir_56_10">some text here</xref> guidance related to generally accepted auditing standard</para>
            <para> the effective dates for FASB ASU No. 2018 <xref href="aag-dep1_1.01">some text here</xref></para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.01">
                <para>text here <xref href="fot_79_ut">some text here</xref></para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here<xref href="aag-dep1_01">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
            <section id="aag-dep1_2.01">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_02">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_02">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>ces, including engagements for entities in specia</para>
            <para>example, a large calendar-year public insurance en</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.02">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <xref href="tih52_23">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">
            <para>text <xref href="aag-dep1_1.02">some text here</xref> here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>early application may do so as of the beginning</para>
            <para>Other auditing publications have no authoritative status;</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_08">
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">some text here</xref></para>
                <para>text <xref href="nov1_22">some text here</xref> here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
            </section>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

**Expected output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book id="book_id">
    <title>Generally Accepted Accounting Principles</title>
    <chapter id="chapter_id" role="ls_level_2">
        <chapterinfo>
            <titleabbrev>Chapter_abb</titleabbrev>
            <title>Chapter_title</title>
        </chapterinfo>
        <section id="aag-dep1_01">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>containing auditing <!--<xref href="fir_56_10">-->some text here<!--</xref>--> guidance related to generally accepted auditing standard</para>
            <para> the effective dates for FASB ASU No. 2018 <xref href="aag-dep1_1.01">some text here</xref></para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.01">
                <para>text <!--<xref href="fot_79_ut">-->some text here<!--</xref>--> here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here<xref href="aag-dep1_01">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
            <section id="aag-dep1_2.01">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_02">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_02">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>ces, including engagements for entities in specia</para>
            <para>example, a large calendar-year public insurance en</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.02">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <!--<xref href="tih52_23">-->some text here<!--</xref>--></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">
            <para>text <xref href="aag-dep1_1.02">some text here</xref> here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>early application may do so as of the beginning</para>
            <para>Other auditing publications have no authoritative status;</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_08">
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">some text here</xref></para>
                <para>text <!--<xref href="nov1_22">-->some text here<!--</xref>--> here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
            </section>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

**My XSL Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="xref">
        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches(@href, '^(aag_([0-9]+)([b]+))')">
                <xsl:comment>&lt;xref href="<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>"&gt;</xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:comment>&lt;/xref&gt;</xsl:comment>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xref>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xref>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using tunnel-parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
  version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
        <!-- To speed up things we here collect all section/@id  and send them as tunnel param -->
        <xsl:with-param name="sectionIds" as="xs:string*" tunnel="yes" select="descendant::section/@id"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="xref">
    <xsl:param name="sectionIds"  as="xs:string*" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(@href=$sectionIds)">
        <xsl:comment>&lt;xref href="<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>"&gt;</xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:comment>&lt;/xref&gt;</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xref>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xref>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the whole document needs to be looked up for the section id then a key can help; or in XSLT 2/3 you could even search a subtree; the following uses a key to search the whole doc for a matching section id:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:key name="section" match="section" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="xref[not(key('section', @href))]">
    <xsl:comment>&lt;xref href="<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>"&gt;</xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:comment>&lt;/xref&gt;</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to restrict the search to e.g. the containing `chapter` use e.g. `match="xref[not(key('section', @href, ancestor::chapter))]"` as the match pattern instead.

That is XSLT 3. If you really continue to use an XSLT 2 processor then replace the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

from your code.

Comment: Nice solution. Even less code.

Comment: Thanks Martin, It's great helpful

Comment: After resolving the above scenario with your code, I have got another scenario for xref/@href cross reference

Comment: We have keep the all xml files in the folder structure but xref reference will be in the any folder.

Comment: XML file in the folder: ppa-edi---->all xml files with <section id="aag-dep_01" but other folder have ppa-adt---->all xml file with <xref href="fot_79_ut">text here</xref> then we are unable to find the xref cross reference so comment the 'xref' if we will not find the section/@id, This scenario will within same folder xml files or with in other folder xml files, Can you suggest, Please help

Comment: @KitaAnsari, please raise that new issue as a new, separate question where you provide all the necessary details in the question text.